# how to prevent user from access to main page if he wasn't logged in?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using js vanilla with html and pure php
I made sign up and login pages with database.
when user logged  in login page successfully, it will execute

```
sessionStorage.setItem('logged',"loggedIn");
```

then redirect user to ' / ' the main page.
Everything is good until now.
However, if I changed the URL manually it would access to main page directly!
so how to check if user logged in before loading main page?
I realised I should use sessionStorage.getItem and check it but where I should use it in js?

Comment: This should be using a server-side session mechanism in the first place. Then you can check the login status in the session, _before_ you return content to display.

Comment: Your current implementation is mighty pointless to begin with, because any user who knows how it works, could just visit your site, open the browser console and input `sessionStorage.setItem('logged',"loggedIn");` there directly … and would be considered as “logged in” by your site from there on.

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate? Is this a REST API you are making requests to?

If so then in your front end on the index.html page, include a script tag where you run a conditional regarding the loggedIn session you are storing.

If the session does not exist then redirect them to the login page (i.e `window.location.href = "/login"`).

For such use cases, React is a great option to consider, just putting it out there.

I'd like to mention however, this is a very Insecure way of verifying the users authorization. Use a JWT.